# Three.js buildwithchrome-like project

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to Three.js. I have found this library in my search for an Open Source project upon which to build a very simple virtual construction environment. I have in mind something like [buildwithchrome](https://www.buildwithchrome.com) which would allow one to create an object from a set of about a dozen parts (which I would be exporting from SolidWorks).

Do you know of such a Three.js project that, just like buildwithchrome, shows a list of parts and allows the user to select, drag, drop, translate, rotate, remove, snap / unsnap parts and move the camera around?

That would be great, since I could use it as a starting point and concentrate my efforts on changing the list of parts and the way the snap together, instead of having work on handling user interactions.

Comment: The link is broken...

Comment: Oups, thanks. Fixed now!

Comment: Nice! Feel free to share your solution with us. It could be useful for other users.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't have such a solution (yet!), I'm looking for one!

Answer (score 1):

I have found this which comes closest to what I was looking for: [Mecabricks](http://www.mecabricks.com/en/workshop). It's not an open source project, but, functionally, it's pretty much exactly what I had in mind and it's built with Three.js.

Comment: just check this three.js example to better compare mecabricks with three.js capabilities https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_animation_authoring